# Finding where ciso646 is included?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm coming back to an old project (Visual Studio 2022, C++20), and when I try to compile it, I get the warning

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\ciso646(15,47): error C4996: '_Header_ciso646': warning STL4036:  is removed in C++20. You can define _SILENCE_CXX20_CISO646_REMOVED_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX20_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to suppress this warning.

Is there an easy way find the file which is including this header? I'm including several external (source) libraries.

If I search "Entire solution" in VS for "ciso646", I find nothing.

Comment: Most probably in an external library - searching solution doesn't scan outside libraries. Just silence the warning.

Comment: Preprocessing the cpp files might help

Comment: Compile with `/showIncludes`